# Woocommerce Klarna checkout layout modification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, klarna

I am integrating my online shop with Klarna payment provider. Klarna checkout should overwrite the regular Woocommerce checkout page. The Klarna checkout is visible on the page BUT so is the regular Woocommerce checkout information - that should be removed. Additionally, Klarna checkout should be full screen (now it is in some grid).

[Checkout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGozZ.png)

Would appreciate if anyone can advice!
I tried to remove custom CSS from my theme's additional CSS but that did not help.

https://senjacosmetics.com/shop/

Wordpress, theme Ellie with Woocommerce plugin

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: I edited the description. Need is to 1) remove the standard Woocommerce checkout from the page 2) make the Klarna checkout appear full screen.

Comment: I added this to CSS and that removed the grid issue: form.woocommerce-checkout {
grid-template-columns: unset;
grid-template-rows: unset;
grid-template-areas: unset;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the order review:

This code on functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
```

Or copy the checkout/review-order.php template to your child theme, and modify it.